# Updating powershell from 5.1 to 6.1

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell

I would like to use the `test-path` command in powershell. According to the official [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/test-json?view=powershell-7.2#description), this was introduced in Powershell version 6.1.

Unfortunately, I am running version 5.1 ion my Windows 10 machine. The [official page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.2#upgrading-existing-windows-powershell) for installing updating powershell does not list 6.1 as one of the possible updates.

Is it possible to update powershell to its latest version in my computer? I'm a bit surprised because I've periodically run the Windows 10 updates several times since I got this computer.

Comment: There is no “upgrading” PowerShell 5.1 to PowerShell 6.1, PowerShell 6.1 (which by the way is NOT the current version) can only be installed alongside PowerShell 5.1. You will want to install PowerShell from the current MSI from its GitHub page

Comment: That seems strange to me. Why has Microsoft set it up where they are different programs as opposed to a new version of the same program?

Comment: I have no idea Microsoft hasn’t made their reasoning know. I just know PowerShell 7.2 isn’t an upgrade to PowerShell 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to update powershell to its latest version in my computer?

PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell (Core) 7.2 can only be concurrently installed. All past, present, and future PowerShell Core releases can be found on its GitHub page [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases). All you have to do is install it with the MSI file for the release you want.

> I'm a bit surprised because I've periodically run the Windows 10 updates several times since I got this computer.

PowerShell Core is not yet a feature of any version of Windows and must be installed manually by the end user. The differences between PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell Core are documented by Microsoft [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.2#:%7E:text=Product%20terminology%20used%20in%20the%20documentation%201%20PowerShell,%28core%29%20-%20PowerShell%20built%20on%20.NET%20Core.%20)